# Mostrar últimos 7 regisros

Tags: php, array, mysqli, select, limit

Tengo el siguiente código, que funciona bien, pero me muestra los primeros 7 registros y lo que deseo es que muestre los 7 últimos. Como lo logro?

```
$sql="SELECT nombre, apellidos, estado FROM personal LIMIT 7";
`$sql="SELECT nombre, apellidos, estado FROM personal LIMIT 7";
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);


    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){`$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

Muchas gracias y saludos cordiales

Comment: Usa un `ORDER` en la query que ordene de manera descendente por el campo que te sirva de referencia para saber cuales son los últimos registros (un ID autoincremental, un campo tipo timestamp de la fecha y hora en la que se creó el registro...)

Comment: Justamente eso estaba redactando como respuesta, es lo mejor que considero que puede hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Como aporte, puedes anexarle a tu consulta un order by de manera descendente al campo que uses como pk, de esta manera lo que haces es que vas a dejar los ultimos registros como primeros.

```
$sql="SELECT nombre, apellidos, estado FROM personal ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 7";
```

Sería reemplazar el ID por el nombre de tu campo que usas como el identificador o primary key.

Espero te sirva,

Saludos

Comment: Mil gracias, lo implementaré así.